# How to find $\Gamma(N/2+1)$?

Tags: integration, factorial, gamma-function

I started exploring the gamma function and I stumbled upon this paper for my high school essay [Volume and Surface Area of anN-Sphere](http://www.hep.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/nsphere.pdf). There it says that $\Gamma(\dfrac12)=\sqrt{\pi}$ and $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$. But I can't quite catch why when finding $\Gamma(n/2+1)$, we employ the $\Gamma(1/2+1)$. $N$ is not necessarily $1$, is it? So how did they get the final result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeated application of the functional equation $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ yields
$$
\Gamma \left( {\frac{n}{2} + 1} \right) = \frac{n}{2}\Gamma \left( {\frac{n}{2}} \right) = \frac{n}{2}\left( {\frac{n}{2} - 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {\frac{n}{2} - 1} \right) =  \cdots  = \frac{n}{2}\left( {\frac{n}{2} - 1} \right) \cdots \frac{1}{2}\Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right) \\ = \frac{n}{2}\left( {\frac{n}{2} - 1} \right) \cdots \frac{1}{2}\sqrt \pi 
$$
($n$ is odd a positive).

Answer (score 0):

$$\Gamma(x+1) = x \Gamma(x) \implies
\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}+1\right) = \frac{3}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} + 1\right) = \frac{3}{2}\times \frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$